# Android Studio favourite click

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio also cardview in Android Studio. How to make like this in picture, when I have 10 cardview for example and I want to heart or like one cardview also when I exit the app and open app again save this process.

This is picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhiFX.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow see this https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Harshapps: please do not "fix" British English spellings here. "Favourite" is spelled correctly, so we respect the author's preference and leave it alone. The US variant is acceptable too, but only where the author would normally use that themselves. The same goes for other British spellings such as "colour", "tyre", "centre", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use Paper DB. You can find the code here: https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

First, add this code to your dependecies:

```
compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
```

Then, initialize it in java by saying `Paper.init(*context*)`

Finally, I would make an ArrayList which contains the indexes of the cards that users have liked, and save that in the database. The database uses a key/value system so you just write:

```
Paper.book().write("likeList", likedArrayList)
```

Then the next time the user opens your app, you can get the likedArrayList again by saying `ArrayList<Integer> likedArrayList = Paper.book().read("likeList")`, and then iterate through the list like normal. Another way to do this would be shared preferences, and if you have a lot of items, maybe look into SQLite.